# Is it necessary to migrate old (La)TeX questions from SO to TeX.SE?

Tags: discussion, migration

There are about [2011 old (La)TeX related questions in SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/latex). Is it necessary to migrate them to TeX.SE? Will it be a heavy task?

Comment: See [Policy on migrating questions from another StackExchange site?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/869)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I can support this *but only if...*

1. The question is not just good, but GREAT
2. It is STRONGLY on topic at the target site
3. You feel VERY STRONGLY it belongs here

If *all* of those criteria aren't met, it is probably best to let the question stay where it is.

Answer (score 12):

No. It's always been clear that the existence of new SX sites does not mean that there is *no* overlap with the main site. For example, questions on the detail of LaTeX programming may well fit within the remit of StackOverflow. At the same time, it seems pretty clear that the idea was never to 'flood' new sites by migrating questions which are no longer active. There is no real gain for anyone.

Answer (score 4):

In my opinion, migrating old LaTeX questions from SO to tex.sx  is a bad thing in many cases. The reason is that -- because of SO's higher number of users -- these question are on a quite different scale with regard to upvotes and number of views. Case in point: [This](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/9363/510) migrated question has the second highest number of upvotes at tex.sx (66), has generated the answer with the highest number of upvotes (87) and has about 39k views. (The only other question with >10k views at tex.sx is [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/13370/510) one which nearly caused a flame war.) Mass-migrating of old SO questions will completely destroy tex.sx's benchmark of what "Good questions" and "Good Answers" are. Don't do it.

Comment: IIRC, the migration votes/views issue has been fixed and votes/views are reset to 0 on migration.

Comment: @Caramdir: I've never heard of that - is this a recent change? According to [this meta.SO answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78452/migrated-posts-lose-their-pre-migration-reputation/88066#88066), lockstep is quite right.

Comment: @Hendrik: Apparently I remembered incorrectly (see also [this meta.SO question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87031/reset-votes-on-migrated-questions)). Though the [migrated questions list](http://tex.stackexchange.com/tools?tab=migrated) would imply that questions are usually migrated with very low vote and view counts.

Comment: @Caramdir: The _recently asked and immediately migrated_ question have low vote and view counts, and are no problem. I fully agree with lockstep that old questions with high vote and view counts shouldn't be migrated anymore.